# Symbolic attributes observation c++

Tags: c++, observer-pattern

I have the following problem. Consider the scheme:
[image]

in the draw class I have:

```
Box* b1 = new Box();
Box* b2 = new Box();
Box* b3 = new Box();
Box* b4 = new Box();

b1->setArea(20);
b2->setArea(30);
b3->setArea( b1->getArea() * 7/3 + b2->getArea() / 5 );
b4->setArea( b3->getArea() + b1->getArea() );
```

I want the following behavior of the system:

- If i change the Area of b1 ( i.e. b1->setArea(25) ) i want that the other boxes change the area accordingly with the above  expressions ( i.e. i want that b2 keeps  its area, but b3 and b4 change their areas as b1->getArea()*7/3 + b2->getArea()/5 and b4 as b3->getArea() + b1->getArea() respectively). This means that  an update of  the area of b1 automatically update the areas of b3 and b4.

I wonder how should I proper implement this feature with C++?

I looked at observer pattern, but it seems that is not applicable in this situation, is this rigth?

Thanks

Comment: Use composition (i.e. boxes own other boxes).

Comment: I cannot do that. The boxes have own life! I need a sort of symbolic computation, or something like this. I need something that can store both the attribute subjected to the observing mechanism, the expression to compute it and the list of attributes that observe it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if the "boxes" were observing a single "event" in the system, like "BOX_AREA_CHANGED" with "b1" as an argument, they could all then change their own areas as needed.

So this does feel like an "observer" pattern.  The issue will be with getting all the participants (the boxes) to attach/detach as needed when they are created/destroyed.  Also, you want them to register for specific events with granularity so you can target their actions easily.  If all the boxes respond to "BOX_AREA_CHANGED" but only a few of them respond to "BOX_MOVED", you don't want the former responding when the latter message is the change that occurred.

I put together something like this called Notifier. Here is the basic gist of it:

1. The Observer is a singleton with keys (enumerated values, not strings) for Subjects to register interest in.  Because it is a singleton, it always exists.
2. Each subject is derived from a common base class.  The base class has an abstract virtual function Notify(...) which must be implemented in derived classes, and a destructor that removes it from the Observer (which it can always reach) when it is deleted.
3. Inside the Observer itself, if Detach(...) is called while a Notify(...) is in progress, any detached Subjects end up on a list.
4. When Notify(...) is called on the Observer, it creates a temporary copy of the Subject list.  As it iterates over it, it compare it to the recently detached.  If the target is not on it, Notify(...) is called on the target.  Otherwise, it is skipped.
5. Notify(...) in the Observer also keeps track of the depth to handle cascading calls (A notifies B, C, D, and the D.Notify(...) triggers a Notify(...) call to E, etc.)

This is what the interface ended up looking like:

```
/* 
 The Notifier is a singleton implementation of the Subject/Observer design
 pattern.  Any class/instance which wishes to participate as an observer
 of an event can derive from the Notified base class and register itself
 with the Notifier for enumerated events.

 Notifier derived classes MUST implement the notify function, which has 
 a prototype of:

 void Notify(const NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T& event, void* data)

 This is a data object passed from the Notifier class.  The structure 
 passed has a void* in it.  There is no illusion of type safety here 
 and it is the responsibility of the user to ensure it is cast properly.
 In most cases, it will be "NULL".

 Classes derived from Notified do not need to deregister (though it may 
 be a good idea to do so) as the base class destructor will attempt to
 remove itself from the Notifier system automatically.

 The event type is an enumeration and not a string as it is in many 
 "generic" notification systems.  In practical use, this is for a closed
 application where the messages will be known at compile time.  This allows
 us to increase the speed of the delivery by NOT having a 
 dictionary keyed lookup mechanism.  Some loss of generality is implied 
 by this.

 This class/system is NOT thread safe, but could be made so with some
 mutex wrappers.  It is safe to call Attach/Detach as a consequence 
 of calling Notify(...).  

 */


class Notified;

class Notifier : public SingletonDynamic<Notifier>
{
public:
   typedef enum
   {
      NE_MIN = 0,
      NE_DEBUG_BUTTON_PRESSED = NE_MIN,
      NE_DEBUG_LINE_DRAW_ADD_LINE_PIXELS,
      NE_DEBUG_TOGGLE_VISIBILITY,
      NE_DEBUG_MESSAGE,
      NE_RESET_DRAW_CYCLE,
      NE_VIEWPORT_CHANGED,
      NE_MAX,
   } NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;

private:
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T;

   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_MAP_T;
   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T>::iterator NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T;

   typedef vector<Notified*> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T;
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T;

   NOTIFIED_MAP_T _notifiedMap;
   NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T _notifiedVector;
   NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T _mapIter;

   // This vector keeps a temporary list of observers that have completely
   // detached since the current "Notify(...)" operation began.  This is
   // to handle the problem where a Notified instance has called Detach(...)
   // because of a Notify(...) call.  The removed instance could be a dead
   // pointer, so don't try to talk to it.
   vector<Notified*> _detached;
   int32 _notifyDepth;

   void RemoveEvent(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T& orgEventTypes, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   void RemoveNotified(NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T& orgNotified, Notified* observer);

public:

   virtual void Reset();
   virtual bool Init() { Reset(); return true; }
   virtual void Shutdown() { Reset(); }

   void Attach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for a specific event
   void Detach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for ALL events
   void Detach(Notified* observer);

   /* The design of this interface is very specific.  I could 
    * create a class to hold all the event data and then the
    * method would just have take that object.  But then I would
    * have to search for every place in the code that created an
    * object to be used and make sure it updated the passed in
    * object when a member is added to it.  This way, a break
    * occurs at compile time that must be addressed.
    */
   void Notify(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T, const void* eventData = NULL);

   /* Used for CPPUnit.  Could create a Mock...maybe...but this seems
    * like it will get the job done with minimal fuss.  For now.
    */
   // Return all events that this object is registered for.
   vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> GetEvents(Notified* observer);
   // Return all objects registered for this event.
   vector<Notified*> GetNotified(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T event);
};

/* This is the base class for anything that can receive notifications.
 */
class Notified
{
public:
   virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const void* eventData) = 0;
   virtual ~Notified();

};

typedef Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;
```

NOTE:  The Notified class has a single function, Notify(...) here.  Because the void* is not type safe, I created other versions where notify looks like:

```
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, int value); 
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const string& str);
```

Corresponding Notify(...) methods were added to the Notifier itself.  All these used a single function to get the "target list" then called the appropriate function on the targets.  This works well and keeps the receiver from having to do ugly casts.

This seems to work well.  The solution is posted on the web [here](http://www.nonlinearideas.com/tools-you-build-part-i-observer/) along with the source code.  This is a relatively new design, so any feedback is greatly appreciated.